# Magento 2 - Create Product attribute programmatically without InstallData

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, catalog

We need to create a script that creates product attributes.

Product attribute comes from third-party API when creating a product attributes its checks attribute is available or not.

If that is not available then it creates at that time product attributes.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes I have got a solution for creating attributes using script and API

1. create attribute using Magento 2 default API
   `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/rest/all/V1/products/attributes`
2. check attributes available or not using API
   `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/api/Product/ProductAttribute/Options/{attribute_id}`
3. get attribute id from attribute code using rest API
   `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/rest/all/v1/products/attributes/{attributecode}`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps

1. Log in to Admin Panel
2. Navigate to Stores > Attributes > Product
3. Click “Add New Attribute“

Fill-up the required details and save it, after that assign that attribute, specific attribute set.

Comment: I need to create a script not need to create a manual attribute from the admin

Comment: As you have mentioned it you don't want to create it using install data, so use upgrade data.

Comment: I have mentioned Script it means need to create programmatically.